# GAE Search API: custom snippet length

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-search-api

I can't seem to get a custom snippet length:

```
snippet = 'snippet("%s", content, 50)' % search_query
index = search.Index(name='index', namespace='namespace')
start_time = time.time()
results = index.search(
    query=Query(
        query_string=search_query,
        options=QueryOptions(
            limit=10,
            cursor=Cursor(),
            sort_options=SortOptions(
                match_scorer=search.RescoringMatchScorer()),
            returned_expressions=FieldExpression('content_snippet', snippet))))
```

I want a snippet which is 50 characters long, instead of the default 160 characters. According to this documentation, the snippet function can get 3 arguments: the search term, the field to snippet over and an optional snippet length.

It seems as if it's completely ignoring the third parameter I pass... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your indentation was faulty, I don't know if you're mixing tabs and spaces or is this was a copy-paste fault but I have re-formatted it. What documentation are you referring to? I can't seem to find a link in your question. Either add the link or better quote the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that snippets don't work on the devserver. See the documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/devserver

> ## Using the Python Development Server
>
> The Python development server runs on your local machine and emulates most of the Search API's capabilities. However, a few features are not currently available on the server. For the moment, you should not attempt to use the following features when you run on the development server:
>
> ### Functions in expressions
>
> These functions are not available:
>
> - snippet()
> - geopoint()
> - distance()
> - pow()

As [advoretsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1954661) said, `returned_expressions` needs to be an iterable. From the docs:

> **returned_expressions**
>
> An iterable of FieldExpression to evaluate and return in search results.

Further, be sure you import the right `Query` and `QueryOptions`, both are also found in `google.appengine.ext.ndb`. I prefer to import them so they have a prefix, things are better readable then ;-)

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.api import search

# Notice the nice distinction
ndb.Query
search.Query
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try it for myself yet, but according to the reference **returned_expressions** [should be iterable](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/queryoptionsclass?hl=en#QueryOptions_returned_expressions). See also an example on  [Query and Sorting Options](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/options?hl=en) and change to

```
returned_expressions=[FieldExpression('content_snippet', snippet)]
```